# How to exclude a certain part of HTML in cheerio?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I have following HTML and I'd like to get only the contents excluding those in `#F1`. I have tried this, but it's not working:

```
"use strict";

let sample = `

<div  id="main">
    <div class="content1">
        <h2>Status</h2>
    </div>

    <div id="F1" >
        <div class="description">
            <p>some info</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="content2">
        <h2>Status</h2>
    </div>

</div>
`
var cheerio = require('cheerio'),
$ = cheerio.load(sample);

$('#main').not('#F1').map(function(i, el) {
    console.log($(el).html())
})
```

Comment: As `#F1` is inside `#main` you can't just exclude it, you'd have to actually remove it, otherwise it's part of `#main` 's html

Comment: remove works,thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are at least a few ways to do this. Which way is best probably depends on context that hasn't been provided, but here goes:

```js
import cheerio from "cheerio"; // 1.0.0-rc.12

const html = `
<div  id="main">
  <div class="content1">
    <h2>Status</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="F1" >
    <div class="description">
      <p>some info</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content2">
    <h2>Status</h2>
  </div>
</div>
`;
const $ = cheerio.load(html);

// approach 1
console.log([...$("#main > div").not("#F1")]
  .map(e => $(e).text().trim()));

// approach 2
console.log([...$("#main > div:not(#F1)")]
  .map(e => $(e).text().trim()));

// approach 3
console.log([...$("#main [class^='content']")]
  .map(e => $(e).text().trim()));

// approach 4 (destructive)
$("#F1").remove();
console.log([...$("#main > div")]
  .map(e => $(e).text().trim()));
```